# Laravel pines notify

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I'm constantly getting an error when I try to use pines notify. I've included the CSS and the JavaScript:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/jquery.pnotify.default.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.pnotify.js') }}
```

Error in Chrome developer tools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.pnotify.js:912
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index:169

Comment: You should load jQuery before loading the library.

Comment: never thought that was the problem. thanks. :)